# matplotlib hexbin: Which bin has the highest count

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, colorbar

I want to find out which bin has the highest count from the matplotlib.hexbin() function. I need this information, since I want to plot various datasets in various plots, but with the same colorbar range for better comparison.

Comment: Seems like this is more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11645494/1461210

Comment: it sure is. I've must have missed that one